# Problems with running C code in Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I installed VS Express 2012 to learn C language in my University. I create new empty project then add new item to Source Files folder and change Source.cpp to Source.c

"Hello World" runs without problems but when I write simple "for" loop like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        printf("the i value is: %d\n", i);
    }

    getchar();

    return (0);
}
```

It writes me lots of errors:

```
------ Build started: Project: cTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  Source.c
e:\ctest\source.c(7): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
e:\ctest\source.c(7): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
e:\ctest\source.c(7): error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
e:\ctest\source.c(7): warning C4552: '<=' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
e:\ctest\source.c(7): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
e:\ctest\source.c(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
e:\ctest\source.c(9): error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Declare `i` variable in the beginning of the function.

Comment: @AlexFarber Works. thanks. Can You explain why i cannot declare i variable inside the loop.

Comment: @Luchnik Since in c you cannot declare local variables at an arbitrary scope, but only in the beginning of a function code block.

Comment: MSVC is still a C89 compiler; the `for (int i = 0; …)` notation is from C++ and C99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shown in [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/jvrW7m),

> error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
>   note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

I think, this clears your doubt. Declare `i` at the beginning of the function.
The correct code would be like this at [WorkingExample](http://ideone.com/jvrW7m).

From [C99 Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), this is a new feature that was not available earlier.

> Intermingled declarations and code: variable declaration is no longer
>   restricted to file scope or the start of a compound statement (block),
>   similar to C++

About VC++ compiler, direct from [Mr. Herb Stutter's mouth](http://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/),

> Implements Standard C90 exactly (using /TC or naming files as
>   something.c)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your code does not obey to the current C standard under which you compile the code. Declaring int i for loop is allowed in C99 standard. Compile with -std=c99.